# Parse a function input name as an output name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add the data input variable name as an output value in a separate column ($V5 within my function "result).

The inputs are different data values, and would like to save these names in the outputs so I can track where the data is coming from.

I thought this would be fairly straightforward, and that I could use print(deparse(substitute(input))) but this doesn't work.

Can anyone recommend a solution?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

## Inputs ##

input_1 = structure(list(V1 = c("Team_2022", "Team_2022", "Team_2022"), V2 = c("Frank", "Mary", "John"), V3 = c("Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney"), V4 = c(55, 76, 14)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
input_2 = structure(list(V1 = c("Team_2023", "Team_2023", "Team_2023"), V2 = c("Bill", "Mary", "John"), V3 = c("Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney"), V4 = c(113, 23, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
input_3 = structure(list(V1 = c("Team_2024", "Team_2024", "Team_2024"), V2 = c("Frank", "Mary", "Bill"), V3 = c("Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney"), V4 = c(7, 19, 52)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
input_4 = structure(list(V1 = c("Team_2025", "Team_2025", "Team_2025"), V2 = c("Frank", "Mary", "John"), V3 = c("Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney"), V4 = c(46, 44, 88)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

## Teams ##

teams = structure(list(V1 = c("team1", "team2", "team3"), V2 = c("Mary + Frank","Mary + John", "Mary + Bill")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

## Group the inputs into one ##

all_objects = ls()
input_objects = grep("^input", all_objects, value = T)
input_test = as.data.frame(input_obj)

## Function ##

result = function(input, teams) {
  data = teams %>%
  separate_rows(V2) %>%
  left_join(input, by = c("V2" = "V2")) %>%
  replace_na(list(V4 = 0)) %>%
  group_by(V1.x) %>% fill(V1.y, V3) %>%
  summarize(V1.y = first(V1.y),
            V2 = paste(V2, collapse = " + "),
            V3 = first(V3),
            V4 = sum(V4),
            V5 = print(deparse(substitute(input))))
  return(data)
}



all_objects <- ls()
input_objects <- grep("^input_\\d", all_objects, value = T)
input_test <- lapply(input_objects, get)

output = input_test %>%
  lapply(result, teams)  %>%
  bind_rows()

### Current output ###

structure(list(V1.x = c("team1", "team2", "team3", "team1", "team2", 
"team3", "team1", "team2", "team3", "team1", "team2", "team3"
), V1.y = c("Team_2022", "Team_2022", "Team_2022", "Team_2023", 
"Team_2023", "Team_2023", "Team_2024", "Team_2024", "Team_2024", 
"Team_2025", "Team_2025", "Team_2025"), V2 = c("Mary + Frank", 
"Mary + John", "Mary + Bill", "Mary + Frank", "Mary + John", 
"Mary + Bill", "Mary + Frank", "Mary + John", "Mary + Bill", 
"Mary + Frank", "Mary + John", "Mary + Bill"), V3 = c("Sydney", 
"Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", 
"Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney"), V4 = c(131, 90, 76, 
23, 33, 136, 26, 19, 71, 90, 132, 44), V5 = c("input", "input", 
"input", "input", "input", "input", "input", "input", "input", 
"input", "input", "input")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

### Desired Output ###

structure(list(V1.x = c("team1", "team2", "team3", "team1", "team2", 
"team3", "team1", "team2", "team3", "team1", "team2", "team3"
), V1.y = c("Team_2022", "Team_2022", "Team_2022", "Team_2023", 
"Team_2023", "Team_2023", "Team_2024", "Team_2024", "Team_2024", 
"Team_2025", "Team_2025", "Team_2025"), V2 = c("Mary + Frank", 
"Mary + John", "Mary + Bill", "Mary + Frank", "Mary + John", 
"Mary + Bill", "Mary + Frank", "Mary + John", "Mary + Bill", 
"Mary + Frank", "Mary + John", "Mary + Bill"), V3 = c("Sydney", 
"Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", 
"Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney"), V4 = c(131, 90, 76, 
23, 33, 136, 26, 19, 71, 90, 132, 44), V5 = c("input_1", "input_1", 
"input_1", "input_2", "input_2", "input_2", "input_3", "input_3", "input_3", 
"input_4", "input_4", "input_4")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: You need the `deparse(substitute` at the start of function, also not clear why the `print` is inside the `summarise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: the `purrr::map_df()` function has a nice feature to identify inputs lists (ideally named) in final `data.frames`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# dropping V5 as it will be "automatically" computed
result = function(input, teams) {
  data = teams %>%
  separate_rows(V2) %>%
  left_join(input, by = c("V2" = "V2")) %>%
  replace_na(list(V4 = 0)) %>%
  group_by(V1.x) %>% 
  fill(V1.y, V3) %>%
  summarize(V1.y = first(V1.y),
            V2 = paste(V2, collapse = " + "),
            V3 = first(V3),
            V4 = sum(V4)
            # we do not need V5 here anymore
            )
  return(data)
}


l_objects <- ls()
input_objects <- grep("^input_\\d", all_objects, value = T)
input_test <- lapply(input_objects, get)

# name the object list to use the name for identification
names(input_test) <- input_objects

# use purrr map to data.frame with the .id feature
purrr::map_df(input_test, ~result(.x, teams), .id = "V5")

  V5      V1.x  V1.y      V2           V3        V4
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
 1 input_1 team1 Team_2022 Mary + Frank Sydney   131
 2 input_1 team2 Team_2022 Mary + John  Sydney    90
 3 input_1 team3 Team_2022 Mary + Bill  Sydney    76
 4 input_2 team1 Team_2023 Mary + Frank Sydney    23
 5 input_2 team2 Team_2023 Mary + John  Sydney    33
 6 input_2 team3 Team_2023 Mary + Bill  Sydney   136
 7 input_3 team1 Team_2024 Mary + Frank Sydney    26
 8 input_3 team2 Team_2024 Mary + John  Sydney    19
 9 input_3 team3 Team_2024 Mary + Bill  Sydney    71
10 input_4 team1 Team_2025 Mary + Frank Sydney    90
11 input_4 team2 Team_2025 Mary + John  Sydney   132
12 input_4 team3 Team_2025 Mary + Bill  Sydney    44
```

Note that this works without naming the list aswell, though you will only get the list item number, which might be insufficient.

Also the `plyr::ldply` function can be used to bind named lists, generating a new column with the list names in the result data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the `deparse/substitute`, create an argument in `result` for the names as well, and then use that

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
result <- function(input, teams, inputnm) {
  data = teams %>%
  separate_rows(V2) %>%
  left_join(input, by = c("V2" = "V2")) %>%
  replace_na(list(V4 = 0)) %>%
  group_by(V1.x) %>% fill(V1.y, V3) %>%
  summarize(V1.y = first(V1.y),
            V2 = paste(V2, collapse = " + "),
            V3 = first(V3),
            V4 = sum(V4),
            V5 = inputnm)
  return(data)
}
```

-testing

```
input_test %>% 
   pull(input_objects) %>%
   mget(inherits = TRUE) %>%
   imap_dfr(~ result(.x, teams, .y))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   V1.x  V1.y      V2           V3        V4 V5     
   <chr> <chr>     <chr>        <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  
 1 team1 Team_2022 Mary + Frank Sydney   131 input_1
 2 team2 Team_2022 Mary + John  Sydney    90 input_1
 3 team3 Team_2022 Mary + Bill  Sydney    76 input_1
 4 team1 Team_2023 Mary + Frank Sydney    23 input_2
 5 team2 Team_2023 Mary + John  Sydney    33 input_2
 6 team3 Team_2023 Mary + Bill  Sydney   136 input_2
 7 team1 Team_2024 Mary + Frank Sydney    26 input_3
 8 team2 Team_2024 Mary + John  Sydney    19 input_3
 9 team3 Team_2024 Mary + Bill  Sydney    71 input_3
10 team1 Team_2025 Mary + Frank Sydney    90 input_4
11 team2 Team_2025 Mary + John  Sydney   132 input_4
12 team3 Team_2025 Mary + Bill  Sydney    44 input_4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just had one input at a time, simply moving the line for assigning `V5` outside of your `summarize` and `dplyr` pipes would do it:

```
result = function(input, teams) {
  data = teams %>%
    separate_rows(V2) %>%
    left_join(input, by = c("V2" = "V2")) %>%
    replace_na(list(V4 = 0)) %>%
    group_by(V1.x) %>% fill(V1.y, V3) %>%
    summarize(V1.y = first(V1.y),
              V2 = paste(V2, collapse = " + "),
              V3 = first(V3),
              V4 = sum(V4),
              #V5 = print(deparse(substitute(input)))
              )
  data$V5 <- deparse(substitute(input))
  return(data)
}

result(input_1, teams)

#  V1.x   V1.y       V2           V3        V4 V5     
#  <chr> <chr>     <chr>        <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  
#  1 team1 Team_2022 Mary + Frank Sydney   131 input_1
#  2 team2 Team_2022 Mary + John  Sydney    90 input_1
#  3 team3 Team_2022 Mary + Bill  Sydney    76 input_1
```

But your use of lists makes that a bit challenging (it will output `X[[i]]` for that code).

To address this for using `lapply`, I would suggest simply adding an additional input that takes the name and simply assigning it that name, with additional tweaks to the `lapply` function to accommodate it:

```
result = function(input, teams, nme) {
  data = teams %>%
    separate_rows(V2) %>%
    left_join(input, by = c("V2" = "V2")) %>%
    replace_na(list(V4 = 0)) %>%
    group_by(V1.x) %>% fill(V1.y, V3) %>%
    summarize(V1.y = first(V1.y),
              V2 = paste(V2, collapse = " + "),
              V3 = first(V3),
              V4 = sum(V4),
              #V5 = print(deparse(substitute(input)))
              )
  data$V5 <- nme 
  return(data)
}

all_objects <- ls()
input_objects <- grep("^input_\\d", all_objects, value = T)
input_test <- lapply(input_objects, get)

# add in assigning names to the list
names(input_test) <- input_objects 

output = lapply(input_objects, function(x) result(input_test[[x]], teams, nme = x)) %>%
  bind_rows()

#     V1.x  V1.y      V2           V3        V4 V5     
#     <chr> <chr>     <chr>        <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  
#   1 team1 Team_2022 Mary + Frank Sydney   131 input_1
#   2 team2 Team_2022 Mary + John  Sydney    90 input_1
#   3 team3 Team_2022 Mary + Bill  Sydney    76 input_1
#   4 team1 Team_2023 Mary + Frank Sydney    23 input_2
#   5 team2 Team_2023 Mary + John  Sydney    33 input_2
#   6 team3 Team_2023 Mary + Bill  Sydney   136 input_2
#   7 team1 Team_2024 Mary + Frank Sydney    26 input_3
#   8 team2 Team_2024 Mary + John  Sydney    19 input_3
#   9 team3 Team_2024 Mary + Bill  Sydney    71 input_3
#  10 team1 Team_2025 Mary + Frank Sydney    90 input_4
#  11 team2 Team_2025 Mary + John  Sydney   132 input_4
#  12 team3 Team_2025 Mary + Bill  Sydney    44 input_4
```